# Changing the encryption algorithm used for PGP/GPG private key

Tags: gnupg, openpgp, gpg4win

I've read a [number of posts](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/75895/what-concrete-parameters-can-i-change-to-make-my-passphrase-protected-private-gp) regarding changing the algorithm used to encrypt my private PGP keys. However, nothing I have tried seems to work. I am using gpg4win:

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.3.4
libgcrypt 1.9.4
Copyright (C) 2021 g10 Code GmbH
License GNU GPL-3.0-or-later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: C:\Users\[REDACTED]\AppData\Roaming\gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
AEAD: EAX, OCB
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

My `gpg.conf` file located at `C:\Users\[REDACTED]\AppData\Roaming\gnupg\gpg.conf` is

```
personal-digest-preferences SHA512
cert-digest-algo SHA512
default-preference-list SHA512 SHA384 SHA256 SHA224 SHA1 AES256 AES192 AES ZLIB BZIP2 ZIP Uncompressed OCB EAX ks-modify
personal-cipher-preferences AES256 AES192 AES
s2k-mode 3
s2k-cipher-algo AES256
s2k-digest-algo SHA512
s2k-count 65011712
cipher-algo AES256
```

I then change the password via

```
gpg -vv --expert --edit-key A7AA75FD6A11F453DE501E38D3E3B91787699C75
passwd
```

Export the key

```
gpg -vv --cipher-algo AES256 --export-secret-keys A7AA75FD6A11F453DE501E38D3E3B91787699C75 -a > key.txt
```

and then inspect it

```
gpg --list-packets key.txt
```

which then outputs

```
:secret key packet:
    ...
    iter+salt S2K, algo: 7, SHA1 protection, hash: 2,
    ...
```

This would seem to suggest that the key is still encrypted using AES128 (algo 7) and a SHA1 hash.

What am I missing?

Comment: I believe you cannot change the key after created, you have to create a new key.

Comment: @ThoriumBR - I do not want to change the key itself, but rather the symmetric cipher encrypting the key.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever solve this?